# how to get list of users who like my tweet and list of users who quoted retweet my tweet?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterapi-python, sttwitterapi, fhs-twitter-engine

Hello i want to get the list of users who likes my tweet and also the list of users who quoted retweet my tweets and also what to reply the user who reply to my tweets. Is there any apis for all of this in twitter docs? please help

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the current Twitter API is that this is not possible. There are ways to do it - for instance, with the browser plugin [Twitter Block Chain for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/twitter-block-chain/dkkfampndkdnjffkleokegfnibnnjfah?hl=en), but unfortunately, any form of scripting or scraping is forbidden by [Twitter's terms of service](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation) under the threat of a permanent account ban. Anecdotally, I know people who have used these methods and avoided bans, but honestly if you're serious enough about Twitter to learn the API, you probably can't afford to risk it - not to mention that it's against the site rules.

I feel this situation sucks and there's a number of features that could benefit users and actually take the load off of Twitter's moderation teams if users had better API access or were allowed to write simple JavaScript macros, but unless they've extended functionality a lot in the last year or so, this is functionality that can't be done without violating the TOS. Sorry.